# How much slipping and sliding go on during short final?

Tags: landing, autoland, coordinated-flight

#### NOTE: This is not a question about coordinated flight in the pattern. There is no disagreement that hasty skids to turn the plane faster from base to final can and do kill. The question is about what happens once the plane is aligned on final and now continuous micro- and small-adjustments are necessary to precisely land the plane on the centerline.

While flying [Condor](https://www.condorsoaring.com/) the other day, I noticed that when I depend on automated turn coordination it is exceedingly difficult to align the (simulated) glider with the runway. The reason is readily apparent in that a typical glider has a bank rate of less than 30deg/sec, and thus bank corrections happen far too slowly to effectively steer the plane. The world is simply going by too fast for the slow rate to yield the precision required for landing. And from a theoretical controls perspective, this is a poorly damped oscillatory system, which are famous for being touchy to control.

And yet, when actually flying for real, a century of anemically maneuverable aircraft have demonstrated that high roll rate is not a requirement for safe landing. What then is going on?

I hypothesize that while on short final we use the rudder extensively for fine control, while keeping the wings appropriately level for the cross-wind conditions. In other words, we intentionally and unconsciously slip and slide the plane in small amounts, because coordinated turns in this phase of flight are slow and even dangerous.

However, this is merely an uninformed hypothesis, and there is certainly a large body of evidence which can definitely answer this one way or the other. In particular, this must be well understood for autolanding systems.

**Can anyone point to studies which looked at the rudder movement on final approach vs. in standard flight?**

P.S. Anecdotes are interesting, but I think these should be confined to the comment section. I think in order to really answer this question we need results from empirical studies.

Comment: Anecdotally, I (and I think most GA pilots) don't use coordinated turns on short final, mainly because of crosswinds.  Slips are also useful for losing a bit of airspeed, when you come in rather "hot" - as might be the case if you're sharing the runway with commercial jets.  Though the gliders I've flown have spoilers and single wheels, so slips seem less useful there.  Though trying to explain is rather like asking the centipede how it handles all those legs: I don't really think about it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Centipede%27s_Dilemma

Comment: It depends partially on technique, some use crossed controls for crosswind landings, others use crabbing.

Comment: Note that there is a real aircraft that relies on auto-coordination only and lacks separate rudder pedals, the [ERCO Ercoupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ERCO_Ercoupe). Quick search suggests it has a fairly high cross-wind limit of 25 knots too.

Comment: Fwiw, the A320 has auto-coordination all the way to the ground, and pilots use rudder only below 30' to decrab, no rudder on final app whatsoever. Don't think it makes the airbus any harder to control on approach than any other conventional  a/c

Comment: @Radu094 That's true for every aircraft with a yaw damper.

Comment: A bit to be said about the contribution of *thrust* to the lateral control of crab.  The B-52 just stays there, landing with nose pointing off center.  With a glider, one can de-crab at many points in the final.  Some may feel more comfortable to stay coordinated until just before touchdown.   Note the wing sweep of the "52" will couple in a bit of roll, even without ailerons.

Comment: Last week I took up a new glider student for a ride / informal instruction-- he had trouble holding heading-- I took the controls to figure out how I did it-- then I told him "for *small* corrections, it works well to just keep the wings level with ailerons and steer with the rudder.  For larger corrections, you'll need to make more coordinated inputs."  I can also also tell you that when flying a model airplane I typically don't even touch the rudder stick at all on final, unless I'm making a correction for a crosswind, in which case I typically hold a relatively *constant* rudder input

Comment: (ctd) in which case I typically hold a relatively *constant* rudder input to keep the nose *on average* parallel to the runway centerline, while *steering* with the ailerons to actually stay on the extended centerline.  In a full-scale airplane or glider, having the advantage of a ringside view of the situation, I'd be more actively working the rudders with every aileron input, to keep the longitudinal axis of the aircraft *exactly* parallel to the runway centerline, while adjusting my left-right "position" relative to the centerline with the ailerons.

Comment: So, your mileage may vary-- it depends on the specific situation-- but there definitely is some sideslip going on at times--

Comment: @quietflyer Your instructional comment "for small corrections, it works well to just keep the wings level with ailerons and steer with the rudder. For larger corrections, you'll need to make more coordinated inputs." sums up well my suspicion about our inputs on short final.

Comment: PS it's of some relevance to note that the model airplane in question-- as would be true of most model airplanes and most full-scale airplanes as well-- exhibited vastly less "adverse yaw" than any sailplane would.  So again-- your mileage may vary-- it depends on the specific situation, including the specific aircraft involved--

Comment: Related: https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/91403/viable-to-slip-onto-the-center-line

Answer (score 3):

It is fine to slip and slide through a turn when you have enough altitude; doing so while being slow and close to the ground is much less advisable. Coordinating controls in turns is especially important when being slow and low.

The key to a good approach is space: Fly a large pattern so you have enough time to adjust heading and sink rate during the final. It is amazing how well the human mind can interpret small changes in the viewing angle - fly coordinated turns until your flight path is parallel to the runway and adjust flaps and flight speed so the glide path will intersect with the ground maybe 50 m (150 ft) ahead of the point where you intend to touch down. If you are too high, increase speed and shift that imaginary intersection closer to you, and vice versa. When all is adjusted, you should have used up maybe half of the final approach and can enjoy the nice, stabilized approach and prepare for the touchdown. Round out when maybe 3 m (10 ft) high and kick the rudder just when you think the wheel will touch the ground in order to align the fuselage with the direction of movement. Open the speed brakes fully only when the wheel has started rolling. This will produce a great landing.

Use side slipping if you are too high and make sure that your speed is at least 30% higher than stall speed. The direction of the sideslip should be with the nose pointing away from the crosswind so the misalignment between fuselage axis and glide path is small. If this produces a well stabilized approach, do as I said above and end the slip just before the beginning of the flare. But train sideslipping at altitude before doing this for real!

The scale of gusts gets smaller as you approach the ground, so the large ones which can shift the flight path and roll angle considerably should die down as the glider sinks lower. Also, gusts tend to cancel out over time, so you shouldn't be too upset about single ones. In gusty weather you need to fly your approach at higher speed so you have some margin against wind shear close to the ground. Because roll damping decreases and aileron authority increases with increasing speed, being thrown around by gusts indicates that your approach speed is too low.

The glider's inertia is already reason enough that you cannot fly in a coordinated way while being blown around by gusts, so short-term deviations of the yaw string can be disregarded. Your reactions, however, should be coordinated. When flying faster, adverse yaw is lower and it will be easier to keep the controls coordinated.

And if there are still gusts, a glider will find thermals and should not land yet.

Comment: This is great general advice, but once the plane is pretty-much aligned with the runway, and short-lived wind gusts push it around a meter to one side or the other of the centerline, I question if we are truly flying in a coordinated fashion or even if it makes sense to try. My instinct is that roll rate is far too slow to compensate for the quick lateral deviations caused by turbulence and gusts.

Comment: @KennSebesta Agreed, the answer needed improvement. I added a bit about gusts.

Comment: "And if there are still gusts, a glider will find thermals and should not land yet." @PeterKämpf, lol, yes! Still, what I'm missing in these answers is empirical data. What we've been taught is a simplified form of the reality, and the gist of my question is to get at the underlying data for this admittedly small edge case.

Comment: @KennSebesta  a planes response to a gust is dependent on its mass to side surface area.  The force of a gust will take time to build  up lateral velocity.  Keep in mind how strong the wing lift is, and how much horizontal force even a slight roll can generate.  Yes, a very light wing loaded plane will be a bit more "twitchy" in the wind, but "perfect" landings under those conditions should not be expected.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Consider that the Schw. 1-36 has a published roll rate of 15 deg/sec. If a gust banked the plane 10 degrees to the side, which is not uncommon in rowdy conditions, then it would take almost a full second just to neutralize the turn. Then it would take another almost full second to bank 10 degrees opposite to start the correction. Then we add more time to end the correction, etc... We can see that the numbers add up quickly and unfavorably: a turbulent gust which banks the plane cannot be effectively rejected in under 2 seconds when flight is purely coordinated.

Comment: @KenSebesta bank does not equal turn, and frankly, using rudder will not make much difference in controlling a side gust.  Fast and accurate aileron input is what you want.  Remember also, dihedral is helping you here, in addition to "published roll rate".  **use that wing, coordinate with rudder**.  You get 5 degrees in 1/3 second!

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni Bank and turn are related if we are coordinated. So if we hypothesize that we are always in coordinated flight, then when the gust banks the plane, if we are to rigidly follow the rule then we will find ourselves in a decaying coordinated turn to the side of the perturbation. I think from this alone we can quickly conclude that on short final, it is not ideal to maintain perfect coordinated flight. My question is to find data on to what extent it's ideal to deviate.

Comment: @KennSebesta you have opened a very interesting discussion.  It may be helpful to specify what aircraft you are referring to.  *All* turns low and slow are dangerous, coordinated turns are by far the safest.  You may be overestimating the effect of gusts, although  microbursts can overwhelm even the largest of aircraft.  Keep in mind the "side gust" will also affect the tail, pivoting the plane into the wind.  A pilot can feel the gust and react immediately.  Especially under power, a coordinated turn into the wind will hold course while the pilot evaluates.

Comment: @RobertDiGiovanni you make some excellent points there. I definitely hadn't considered how the tail tends to weathervane, helping reject lateral perturbations. I think we're all in agreement there are a lot of tiny factors which sum up to... something. Although it's not clear to me which way that something points so I'm left hoping for some data.

Answer (score 1):

In a cross wind landing one can stay coordinated and crab their way down to the round/flare phase, but over the runway rudder and ailerons have specific purposes.

The rudder points the nose of the plane straight down the center line.  The ailerons are used for lateral control, banking *into* any crosswind component.

For example, a 5 degree roll in a Cessna 172 at 2000 lbs lift would produce sin 5 × 2000 = 174 lbs of side force!  So, even "ponderous" rolling is effective to hold track.

Interestingly, short final can also be flown this way, *at a safe airspeed*.

For example, approaching "cross controlled" in a 172 would be suicidal at 50 knots, but much safer at 65 knots.  Importantly, while on short final,  *flying in a straight line*, slipping is not nearly as dangerous as *in a turn*, where differences in wing tip speed can become critical.

Over the runway, basically one does what is needed to control the aircraft until it is down and stopped.  Effect of rudder will vary with different aircraft.  In a flaring 172, it does little more than yaw the nose back and forth *without appreciably changing the fight path*.

All uncoordinated manuevers should be thoroughly tested at altitude before use in a pattern.

Regarding "the world going by too fast for the slow rate to yield precision", this is definitely true for very light wing loads such as paper airplanes, models, and birds.  Here, the "tricks" of controlling side wind gusts can be seen in the common seagull:  high wing design with *anhedralled* wingtips and *no vertical stabilzer*.  This design automatically banks *into* the wind without excessive yawing.

Full scale aircraft are seen in all shapes and sizes because their much higher wing loading (or mass to surface area) creates a much slower acceleration from a side force, that is more easily controlled.

Answer (score 1):

You could be drifting into dangerous territory (pun intended...hahahah). There should be NO slipping and sliding going on in any airplane or glider on final except for side slips induced on purpose to lose altitude, or for crosswind compensation during the landing flare.

All maneuvering turns in flight must be coordinated. Cross control or skidding maneuvers, close to the ground, except for deliberately induced side slips, invite a spin if the plane gets too slow and stalls.

The technique you are describing, in effect, consists of pointing the nose at the target (the runway) with rudder because it gets results faster.  This results in uncoordinated flight, and lots of people have died from spins originating from this habit.

Even in a glider with a ponderous roll rate, all maneuvering turns must be coordinated banked turns to make the necessary heading changes.  You have to think of it in terms of headings on final, and adjustments to headings when required.

Like gliders, large airliners have similarly ponderous roll rates and they make coordinated turns on final like all other airplanes. It takes a bit of patience. If you are drifting off track, you make a heading change, the normal way, with a coordinated turn to a new heading, then another coordinated turn to adjust as required. None of this pointing the nose with rudder stuff.

The thing is, in gliders, you often need large aggressive rudder inputs just ahead of the aileron input to get a coordinated turn in the first place, and that's fine, it's the way gliders have to be flown.  But the objective is still to keep the yaw string straight as possible while maneuvering.

Comment: This is the conventional wisdom, but I'd like to see data to back it up. It's important to note that I'm not asking about pattern maneuvers, but about maintaining the centerline on short final. A 2-33's roll rate is so slow that it's very very challenging to get it to turn quickly, but if I want to make a precise landing on the centerline I need rapid fine control. I suspect that we are doing lots of little skids to keep the nose aligned. Either way, there must be data out there...

Comment: See @quietflyer's anecdotal experience about "for small corrections, it works well to just keep the wings level with ailerons and steer with the rudder. For larger corrections, you'll need to make more coordinated inputs."

Comment: No no no no no no no.   You don't need studies - this is very basic airmanship.   Quiet Flyer is playing with fire.  You will never get me skidding the glider around the keep it lined up except in the last few feet.  It is very bad flying technique and applies to gliders and power planes.  If the string is pointing off to one side and you stall, it's going to roll off on you.  If you're side slipping to stay lined up, wing down and opposite rudder, that's fine if you ensure you have a speed and AOA margin.  But skidding around flat to keep lined up at 100 or 200 feet is asking for trouble.

Comment: I could not agree with you more that if your yaw string is clearly pointing toward uncoordinated flight then you are playing with fire. I think we are talking about very different magnitudes, though. I am not suggesting that we are unconsciously kicking the rudder back and forth, which is what I believe you are concerned about. Instead, I think that we might be using it in such a way that it is not simply a slave to the bank angle, perhaps similarly to how we lead in with the rudder to counteract adverse yaw. And if this is indeed occurring, it is subtle enough to only be clear in the data.